# Why do I get an 'IndexError: list index out of range' when I try to remove a record from my list in the except block

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, try-catch

When I try running this function, I get an Index error: list out of range. The error occurs in the except block of the code when I try to use `list.remove(list[i])`. Not sure why I'm getting the out of range error, and any help would be much appreciated!

I've already tried debugging with various print statements around my function, and I saw that my record is fine, it just throws this error whenever I try to remove the record in my except block.

```
def subnet_insertion_sort(list):
    with open('bad_subnets.csv', 'w') as z:
        # Traverse through 1 to len(list)
        for i in range(1, len(list)):
            # extracts subnet from current list observed in list
            # and casts it as a ip_network objects
            try:
                key_subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(list[i][0]))

                j = i - 1
                # Move elements of list[0..i-1], that are
                # greater than key, to one position ahead
                # of their current position
                while (j >= 0 and key_subnet < ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(list[j][0]))):
                        temp = list[j]
                        list[j] = list[j + 1]
                        list[j + 1] = temp
                        j -= 1
            except:
                print("invalid subnet found: " + list[i][0] +  " on line " + str(i) + ". It has been added to bad_subnets.csv")
                writer_z = csv.writer(z)
                writer_z.writerow(list[i])
                list.remove(list[i])
                continue

        return list
```

My expected result would be that the function runs properly and I received a list without the invalid subnets, but my actual output is the Index error: list out of range.

Comment: Please don't use for your variables identifiers reserved keywords like `list`. It will conflict with the builtin `list()`

Comment: Never change a list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you start your for loop with

```
for i in range(1,len(list))
```

If the length of your **original** list is `10`, it will translate to

```
for i in range(1,10)
```

If you remove items from your list within the loop, that would not change the range. Once the range goes over the length of the current list, it will cause Index Error.

Answer (score 0):

Never change a list, but create a new list instead:

```
def subnet_insertion_sort(ipaddresses):
    valid_addresses = []
    with open('bad_subnets.csv', 'w') as z:
        writer_z = csv.writer(z)
        for i, address in enumerate(ipaddresses):
            try:
                key_subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(address)
            except ValueError:
                print("invalid subnet found: {} on line {} It has been added to bad_subnets.csv".format(address, i)
                writer_z.writerow(address)
            else:
                valid_addresses(key_subnet)
    return sorted(valid_addresses)
```